# What is Android accelerometer’s min and max range?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I would like to know the minimum and maximum range of the accelerometer in Android.

I need it for x,y,z.

What are the exact values of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no "exact values" in general -- it will vary by device. The `Sensor` class has `getMaximumRange()`. Since acceleration can be positive or negative, I would assume you can safely multiply that value by -1 to get the minimum value.

Comment: I agree that the minimum value is the negative of the value returned by getMaximumRange(). Although it is too small to make a difference in most applications, I suspect (due to the two's complement representation of the sensor reading) that the actual positive maximum value is one resolution value less than getMaximumRange().

Comment: Well in fact, I have on my desk a phone with a `Bosch Sensortec GmbH` accelerometer that returns `156.88` for `getMaximumRange()` but shamefully fails to deliver, having a total max range of exactly `39.225403` on each axis (I shaked and crashed the rugged device as hard as I could to test this). So what this method returns is unreliable, event if the sensors report having a high accuracy (they tell so all the time on this device). On the other hand, my Nexus 6P could report range values over `150ms^2` per axis, with a max total acceleration of `135.92858447775066ms^2`.

Answer (score 1):

It measures a physical magnitude!
 I don't really know if there is some practical limit introduced by the hardware-device, but I don't think you're gonna be that fast... Since its a vectorial magnitude, the sign means the sense of your movement.

PD: I'm assuming you mean `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` events values.

Comment: Every hardware sensor has limits. Driver developers should have stated these limits. If a value beyond that limit is reached the value reported will be clipped.