# Accelerometer's Min and Max value range and sensor data conversion

Tags: android, c, accelerometer, android-sensors, motorola

I have moto g 16 GB device from Motorola.  It has LIS3DH 3 axis Accelerometer.

For reading Max and Min value of Accelerometer i have used this APIs.

```
getMaximumRange()
```

[Some says](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63828) its shows `zero to Pick` or `pick to pick`

But for my device i get value  **39.24**

so i though 39.24 / 9.8 =  ~4.00 s my range is +/- 4g

But when i simply read x,y,z data and store it in file and see the values when giving max acceleration to the my smart phone then its shows values up to **76 m/sec2**

What the meaning of this?

Is this bug of my device?

how to convert this values in +- 2g values. my algorithm wants value in +-2g format how to give that?

how to perform cut of or down sampling of sensor data values ?

Comment: According to the data sheet, the accelerometer is dynamically configurable to different ranges. Maybe you can use introspection to see if the implementing sensor class has additionals methods to dynamically change the sensor range. Sensor data sheet: http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM89/SC444/PF250725?icmp=pf250725_pron_pr_feb2014  I also recommend reading http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thanks was just reading that only

Comment: 1G is 32' per (sec*sec) so 76m per (sec*sec) is (approximately) 228' per (sec*sec) so 228/32 = 7.125G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moto g has dynamic configurabale senser. Initially it is configured in 4g mode. But when you gives more acceleration to your mobile it changes it sensor mode and switch to 8g and still you give more acceleration then it gest 16 g mode automatically. After some time it get back to 4g mode.

You can have on Sensocr Accurcay change callback on this range change.