# How to take the maximum value of the Gyroscope LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm writing an Android game that uses a gyroscope and I need to take the largest possible gyroscope value.

---

I know how to get the gyroscope value.
I need to take the largest possible gyroscope Z value because each telephone has a different gyroscope and a different maximum value of the gyroscope.

Comment: What to you mean for "the largest possible gyroscope value"?

Comment: this is the maximum value that the gyroscope can register

Comment: How about making calibration on your own? Save current maximum values somewhere and if sometime you read bigger value that saved just update saved one.

Answer (score 0):

You can `implement a SensorEventListener` in your activity or in a specific class.

Then you can get values from gyroscope instantiating a SensorManager

```
SensorManager sensorManager;
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Then set a SensorSensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE

```
Sensor gyroscope;
gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
```

And override these 2 methods

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // Here you get values from the gyroscope
    if (event.sensor == gyroscope) {
        double accX = event.values[0];
        double accY = event.values[1];
        double accZ = event.values[2];
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}
```

For more specific references: [Android motion Sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion)

P.S.
Don't forget to check if the sensor is `!= null`

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods in libgdx that will allow you to get the max value for accelerometers as they are hardware based and no API exists AFIAK.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739143/android-accelerometer-max-values) it appears to be that typical values are +/- 2G